# Getting codes regarding image zoom on mouse hover to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying for over a week to get this HTML code [in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/swarad07/pen/JxOpea) to work but to no avail.

The above code is about zooming an image on mouse hover with panning. I have put all the codes into an HTML constructed using Notepad++. I would sincerely appreciate instructions as to where I went wrong and how to get it to work:
My HTML codes (together with CSS and JavaScript) taken from the link above and paste into the HTML:

I couldn't get the images to display on my HTML. I really could not fully understand the codes due to my minimum experience. I wonder if there are further declarations I need to add at the `<head>` sections of the HTML - the links to runtime?

```js
$('.product-img--main')
  // tile mouse actions
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children('.product-img--main__image').css({
      'transform': 'scale(' + $(this).attr('data-      scale') + ')'
    });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).children('.product-img--main__image').css({
      'transform': 'scale(1)'
    });
  })
  .on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $(this).children('.product-img--main__image').css({
      'transform-origin':
        ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' +
        ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 + '%'
    });
  })
  // tiles set up
  .each(function() {
    $(this)
      // add a image container
      .append('<div class="product-img--main__image"></div>')
      // set up a background image for each tile based on data-image attribute
      .children('.product-img--main__image').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('data-image') + ')'
      });
  });
```

```css
product-img--main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.product-img--main__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  transition: transform .5s ease-out, -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="product-img--main" data-scale="1" data-image="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200">
  </div>
  <div class="product-img--main" data-scale="1.2" data-image="  https://picsum.photos/1200/1200">
  </div>
  <div class="product-img--main" data-scale="1.6" data-image="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200">
  </div>
  <div class="product-img--main" data-scale="2" data-image="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200">
  </div>
  <div class="product-img--main" data-scale="2.2" data-image="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200">
```